# A first order non-homogeneous initial value problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, initial-value-problems

Does $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=-y+\sin(x^2)$ has a unique and well defined solution in $y\in[0,\infty)$ for any $y(0)\in\mathbb{R}$? For a unique solution to exists, do we need $\sin(x^2)$ to be locally Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: this equation has no soluution in the known elementary functions!

Comment: What do you mean by y(0)? Do you mean that both y and x are parameterized by some other variable, and the value of y when this variable is zero is known? Do you mean that the value of y when x is zero is known?

Comment: I am looking for an argument for existence and uniqueness of the solution. Is $\sin(x^2)$ locally Lebesgue intergrable? If that is true then we have guarantees that a solution exists and is unique.

Comment: @user85310520 You do not need to mess with Lebesgue stuff here. This is a standard existence and uniqueness application. I left an elaboration down below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint :** This is a classic example of elaborating an existence and uniqueness case by Piccard's or Peano's Theorem and via Lipschitz continuity. I'll provide a general elaboration down below.

---

Let the differential equation problem of the specific problem of an initial value, be :

$$y' = -y + \sin(x^2), \quad y(x_0)=y_0 $$

Consider the function :

$$f(x,y) = -y + \sin(x^2)$$

Then, it's obvious that $D_f = \mathbb R^2$ and that the function $f$ is continuous over $\mathbb R^2$.

Then, following from Piccard's Theorem of Existence (or Peano's respectively), the given initial value problem has a solution because $f$ is continuous, or in other words, $f$ is continuous on an interval of the form :

$$D = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : |x-x_0|<a, \space |y-y_0| < b\}, \space \text{where} \space a,b>0$$

This means that a solution for the IVP exists in $D$ and is well defined in it.

To proceed about the uniqueness, you need to show that $f_y$ is bounded, or in other words $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

The derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$ is :

$$f_y = \frac{\partial (-y + \sin(x^2))}{\partial y} -1$$

which clearly yields a bounded/surrounded case, as for :

$$\lim_{y\to \pm \infty} f_y=-1$$

This means that the solution is unique.

**Note 1 :** Manipulating the case for $x_0 = 0$ and a specific initial value will yield more specific results, as for the existence and uniqueness in $[0,\infty)$.

**Note 2:** Take into account that the existence and the uniqueness of a solution to a given IVP **does not necessarily mean** that one can find the solution in terms of standard functions.

Comment: Sorry I ask, where is all this taught? Is it real analysis

Comment: @KingTut A complete elaboration of existence and uniqueness theorems are provided with their applications and proofs in classes as : Ordinary Differential Equations, Partial Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, Control Theory etc. The differential problems are considered a category of analysis.

Comment: Thank you a lot, will look into ode in detail.

Comment: @KingTut You could take a brief look [here](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~tyson/existence.pdf) .

Comment: Rebellos, can you give a reference text for that covers the existence and uniqueness of $y'=-y+f(x)$? what kind of general condition we need to require on f(x) to guarantee uniqueness and existence of the results?

Comment: @user85310520 The text I gave you mentions the case for the IVP : $$x'=f(t,x), \quad x(t_0) = x_0$$ This is the same as the case here : $$y'=f(x,y), \quad y(x_0) = y_0$$ The symbols are just not the same, this doesn't mean anything. Instead of $y$ you could have $z$ and instead of $x$ you could have $w$. My elaboration on the answer also considers the same case scenario. Don't get confused by different variables :)

Comment: Actually the reference text I mentioned in the comment above is for the case : $$y' = f(x,y), \quad y(x_0) = y_0$$ Did you read it ? This is exactly the case for : $$y' = -y + g(x)$$ since you can let $$f(x,y) = -y + g(x)$$. The case of $f(x,y)$ covers everything possible.

Comment: Thank you Rebellos. What I meant was a text book, so, I can read more on the subject.

Comment: @user85310520 No problem ! Well, I guess "Elementary Differential Equations" by Boyce - Diprima is a commonly known book. I am Greek though and most of my strict knowledge about differential problems came on my dynamical system course in which we used a Greek book + textbooks, which I guess 1) you cannot find them 2) you probably aren't Greek.

Comment: I also wonder what is the least restrictive condition on $g(x)$ so that $y'=-y+g(x)$ is guaranteed to have a unique and well defined solution in $[0,\infty)$. I think it is that g(x) should be locally Lebesgue integrable. Lebesgue integrable functions do not have to be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's much easier than using general theorems about existence annd uniqueness. In a first-semester DE course one learns a method of solving first-order linear equations, and, unlike a lot of things one learns in that course, the algorithm essentially contains a proof that it's correct.

> > If $g$ is continuous then $y'+y=g$, $y(0)=a$ has a unique solution.

Proof: Since $e^t\ne0$, $y'+y=g$ is equivalent to $$e^{t}y'+e^ty=e^tg(t),$$or $$(e^tg(t))'=e^tg(t).$$

But since $e^tg(t)$ is continuous, elementary calculus show there is a unique function $f$ such that $$f'(t)=e^tg(t),\quad f(0)=a.$$

(Existence: Let $f(t)=a+\int_0^t e^sg(s)\,ds$. Uniqueness: If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two solutions then $(f_a-f_2)'=0$, so $f_1-f_2$ is constant. But $f_1(0)-f_2(0)=0$.)